# git ignore specific directories

Tags: git, github, gitignore, specification-pattern

I wanted to recently upload my dotnetnuke website on git, now my website has gigs of images which i don't want to upload over git.

I was searching on GIT and came across .gitignore file which gets created during repository creation, GIT has a documentation about ignorning files/folders and it's specific sub-folder, however it does not seems to work in my case.

Here's my folder structure:

*******Updated*******

```
.gitignore
public_html/Portals/_default/
public_html/Portals/0/
public_html/Portals/1/
public_html/Portals/110/
```

Now i want to ignore all folders under Portals except Portals/_default. 
I tried based on the specification from GIT:

```
Example to exclude everything except a specific directory foo/bar (note the /* - without the slash, the wildcard would also exclude everything within foo/bar):

    $ cat .gitignore
    # exclude everything except directory foo/bar
    /*
    !/foo
    /foo/*
    !/foo/bar
```

Below is what i tried:

```
!/Portals
/Portals/*
!/Portals/_default
```

But this does not seems to work at all.

Can anyone get me in right direction.

Comment: Remove the first line, and remove the leading slashes (assuming the .gitignore file is adjacent to the Portals folder)

Comment: How does it not work according to your desires?

Comment: @Plato: this does not works either, however i have updated my question to show full directory structure from root.

Comment: Your problem seems to be the `public_html` folder. Move your gitignore into `public_html` or add the `public_html` folder to every line.

Answer (score 5):

From the git [documentation for gitignore](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> Example to exclude everything except a specific directory foo/bar (note the /* - without the slash, the wildcard would also exclude everything within foo/bar):

```
$ cat .gitignore
# exclude everything except directory foo/bar
/*
!/foo
/foo/*
```

Tada!